# Analyzer is complaining about a possible resource leak in multithreaded Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Ok, I am an experienced C++ developer. I am learning Objective-C on the fly while trying to build a fairly substantial Cocoa application. I have done some simpler apps with Cocoa while gearing up for this project and I think I have a good handle on most of the concepts.

The memory management paradigm is still a little vague to me however so I build with the memory analyzer to help me find issues right away, and to be honest it has been awesome and has done more to help me understand Objective-C memory management that any of the documentation.

So here is my question.

I have two threads that communicate with each other using the `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method. They pass objects between each other passed in as the `withObject:` parameter of the method.

Sample code is below:

```
- (BOOL)postMessage:(id <MessageTarget>)sender messageId:(NSInteger)msgId messageData:(void*)data
{
    // message is allocated and retained here. retain count will be +2
    Message* message = [[[Message alloc] initWithSender:sender messageId:msgId messageData:data] retain];
    if(message)
    {
        // message will be released in other thread.
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(messageHandler:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
        // message is released here and retain count will be +1 or 0 depending on thread ordering
        [message release];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)sendMessage:(id <MessageTarget>)sender messageId:(NSInteger)msgId messageData:(void*)data messageResult:(void**)result
{
    // message is allocated and retained here. retain count will be +2
    Message* message = [[[Message alloc] initWithSender:sender messageId:msgId messageData:data] retain];
    if(message)
    {
        // message will be released in other thread. retain count will be +1 on return
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(messageHandler:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:YES];
        if(result)
            *result = [message result];
        // message is released here and retain count will be 0 triggering deallocation
        [message release];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)messageHandler:(Message*)message
{
    // message will have a retain count of +1 or +2 in here based on thread execution order
    if(message)
    {
        switch ([message messageId])
        {
            case 
               ...
            break;

            default:
               ...
            break;
        }
        // message is released here bringing retain count to +1 or 0 depending on thread execution ordering
        [message release];
    }
}
```

The analyzer is complaining about a possible leak of the `Message` object allocated in `postMessage:` and `sendMessage:` but the object is released in `messageHandler:`. The code runs correctly and does not leak, and I suspect the analyzer is simply not able to see that the `Message` object is being released in a different thread.

Now in case you are wondering why I do the second retain in the post/send methods and not in the `messageHandler:` method, it is because the `postMessage:` method is meant to be asynchronous and `[message release]` in the post method may get executed before the `[message retain]` in `messageHandler:` would, leaving me with an invalid object. It would work just fine if I did that in the case of the `sendMessage:` method because it is synchronous.

So is there a better way to do this that would satisfy the memory analyzer? Or maybe a way to give the memory analyzer a hint that the object is in fact being released?

## **Update:**

Torrey provided the answer below but I wanted to clarify what I had to do different from what he suggested.

He suggested using an attribute on my `messageHandler:` method as below

```
- (void)messageHandler:(Message*) __attribute__((ns_consumed)) message;
```

This did not quite work since the object is being passed into `performSelector:` and the analyzer does not see it being passed along to `messageHandler:`

Since the `performSelector:` call is defined by Cocoa and not by me I can not add the attribute to it.

The way around this is to wrap the call to `performSelector:` as follows:

```
- (void)myPerformSelector:(SEL)sel onThread:(NSThread*)thread withObject:(id) __attribute__((ns_consumed)) message waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
{
    [self performSelector:sel onThread:thread withObject:message waitUntilDone:wait];
}
```

Then you can call the wrapper function and the analyzer will see the attribute and not complain about an unbalanced retain/release pair.
In the end I did not like the extra indirection just to get rid of the warning so I used the preprocessor as explained in my comment below. But I could see situations where it could be useful to use this method.

Comment: I have found that I can suppress the warning by wrapping the allocation code with `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__`. This does get rid of the warnings but I consider suppressing a warning a hack and therefore a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need to explicitly transfer reference count ops to the secondary thread when using this API.

- a) Your caller holds a reference when waitUntilFinished is true,
- b) and the implementation behind `+ [NSThread performSelector:…` also does (see: `- [NSRunLoop performSelector:target:argument:order:modes:]`).

There is no need to pass reference count duties for the parameters (or `self`) across threads in this case.

It will either be performed immediately, or `self` and the parameter (it's objc-typed) will be retained while in the other thread's run loop queue (and self and the parameter are released after the object's performed the selector).

*(don't use ref-op `__attribute__`s to shut it up)*

Comment: With my code written as shown above my retain count is 2 inside my `messageHandler:` method as I would expect it to be without an intervening retain inside the `[NSObject performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` method. I would expect it to be 3 with what you describe.

Comment: Wrote a test app and confirmed what you said. I got thrown off on my first test because I was not controlling when the releases where happening and was looking at the retain count after one of the releases had happened. I wish they would clarify that in the docs because some of us newbies don't know the inner workings of cocoa yet. Thanks Justin.

Comment: it's pretty deep within the abstraction layers, but something you can expect from this class of methods (unless the parameters are not objc types or VA lists). not at all a noob question, imo! and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the analyzer happy by judicious use of Clang's `ns_consumed` attribute. As you suggested, this gives the memory analyzer a hint that a release message will be sent to the parameter upon completion of the function call. You would use it like:

```
- (void)messageHandler:(Message*) __attribute__((ns_consumed)) message
```

There is more information on Cocoa memory management annotations in the [Clang analyzer documentation](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#cocoa_mem). You may want to wrap the attribute setting in an NS_COSUMED macro for compatibility with other compilers as suggested on that page.

Comment: This didn't quite work. `__attribute__((ns_consumed))` used on the `messageHandler:` method did not work because the analyzer is not able to trace through the call to `performSelector:`. However by building a wrapper method around `performSelector:` that used the attribute I was able to get the analyzer to be quiet. Example:`- (void)myPerformSelector:(SEL)sel onThread:(NSThread*)thread withObject:(id) __attribute__((ns_consumed)) object waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` I don't like the extra indirection though so I am wrapping the allocation with `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` and calling it good.

Comment: I am still going to call this answered though. Thanks for the help.